# Amount of variance in a given direction?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, covariance

Say we have a multivariate distribution with covariance matrix $P$. What is the variance in the direction of an arbitrary vector $v$?

Eigenvectors of $P$ are the directions of greatest variance, and eigenvalues are informative of how much variance is in the direction of their corresponding eigenvector. How can the variance be calculated for the direction of any other vector?

Comment: note that any vector can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvectors

Comment: Can I assume that the variance explained in that direction is simply the linear combination of weighted variances explained by the eigenvectors?

Comment: it depends on what you mean by 'variance explained'. whatever your mathematical formulation is, should be easy to adapt it if you write things in the eigenvector basis